# How to find when and why Java class interface has changed using SVN/GIT

Tags: java, eclipse, git, svn, eclipse-jdt

**General question: How find when&why Java class interface has changed using SVN/Git**

I'm using Eclipse JDT Core, exactly class SingleNameReference in one of my projects.
To overcome bugs I want to switch from version org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.4.2.v_883_R34x.jar to org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.7.1.v_B76_R37x.jar

The problem is, someone broke interfaces between this versions. 
I want to find out, when it happened, why & what are my alternatives.

**Specific question: How to find in Eclipse Git repo when someone removed code and message why it has been done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this page](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/blame/master/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/SingleNameReference.java), showing you the blame output of that class (and thereby pointing to the change). In case of Eclipse source files, you have a high chance to find such information directly in the github mirrors of their sources.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
git blame filename
```

It will show the author that modified each line in the given filename.